# Unable to parse date and time from csv log into logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I want to combine two fields from a logfile and use the result as timestamp for logstash.

The logfile is in csv format and the date format is somewhat confusing. Date and time are formated like this:

```
Datum => 17|3|19
Zeit => 19:21:50
```

I tried the following code.

```
filter {
  csv {
    separator => ","
    columns => [ "Datum", "Zeit" ]
  }

  mutate {
     merge => { "Datum" => "Zeit" }
  }

  date {
    match => [ "Datum", "d M yy HH:mm:ss" ]
  }

}
```

The merge part seems to work with this result

```
 "Datum" => [
        [0] "17|3|19",
        [1] "23:32:37"
    ]
```

but for the conversion of the date i get the following error message:

```
"_dateparsefailure"
```

can someone please help me?

Comment: Not my langage but I assume that if you call the "date" function it does not inclide time. In python its "datetime".

Comment: You should use mutate#join after the mutate#merge to get a string from your array. Also I think in the date#match, you'd need to keep the `|` in the pattern (like `d|M|yy`).

Comment: @ZF007 In logstash, the [date filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html) will parse the provided field (here `Datum`) with the provided pattern (here `d M yy HH:mm:ss`), which supports date & time.

Comment: @baudsp cheers for the short explanation.. no need to keep me in the loop. Just curated question for SO viability ;-)

Comment: Thanks you @baudsp. Now I'm one step further. The fields for time and date are now successfully merged. unfortunately, the date still cannot be parsed. Result is looking like this now:

`"Datum" => "17|3|19, 23:32:37",
        [0] "_dateparsefailure"`

Comment: @mra My bad, I forgot the `,` in your pattern; I think it should look like this: `d|M|yy,HH:mm:ss`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an event with the following fields:

```
"Datum" => "17|3|19"
"Zeit" => "19:21:50"
```

I got a working configuration:

```
mutate {
     merge => { "Datum" => "Zeit" }
}

mutate {
    join => {"Datum" => ","}
}

date {
    match => [ "Datum", "d|M|yy,HH:mm:ss" ]
}
```

This give me in the output: `"@timestamp":"2019-03-17T18:21:50.000Z"`

Comment: Thank you very much @baudsp. Now it worked. You really made my day :)